# Sending appropriate post requests with python

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to send a post request (that contains specific parameters and values) to a php server (that is instructed to check if the specified request has certain parameters and in that case it will save the values into a database).

With the following curl command i am successfully able to register the request into the server database:

sudo curl -d 'hostname=RegisterTest&ip=127.0.0.1&operatingsystem=testOpsys' -X POST http://localhost/register.php

This is also the curl command that i am trying to simulate with a **python script.** The problem is that i have tried various python syntaxes but i couldn't replicate the curl command and even if the request is sent (and server response is received) the registration will not take place .

```
import requests

url = “http://localhost/register.php”
data = {'hostname=RegisterTest&ip=127.0.0.1&operatingsystem=testOpsys'}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the data as a dictionary.

```py
import requests

data = {
  'hostname': 'RegisterTest',
  'ip': '127.0.0.1',
  'operatingsystem': 'testOpsys'
}

response = requests.post('http://localhost/register.php', data=data)
```

Comment: You were right, it worked ! Thanks so much.